# Count string using regex pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net, wildcard, vb-like-operator

I'm trying to find a solution for the following task, but I’m stuck. Please for a solution.
The code is working fine for counting exact string matches, but what I’m trying to achieve is to find and count words if they are not the same using regex pattern or like operator and wildcard combined, any solution acceptable for example:

Add.ress

add/ress

add-ress

add ress

add*ress

add!ress

add\ress

etc.

Count=6

Only if input textbox.text is "add?ress" count should be 6 (“add ress” excluded because of space ), to make it clear input can be any word but if ? is in between then this rule should apply.
the question mark (?) can by anything except Letters and numbers
else if textbox.text is “add ress” count=1 or if textbox.text is add-ress count=1.
I would like to use ? for any char in between string if it appears on search textbox.

Thank you.

```
Private Sub btnAddTerm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddTerm.Click

    Dim foundAt As Integer = RichTextBox1.Find(txbSearch_Term.Text, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
    Dim text2 As String = RichTextBox1.Text.ToString.ToLowerInvariant

    Dim txbsearch As String = txbSearch_Term.Text

    'Regex.Match(txbsearch, "[-]{1,2}:[/]{2}:[?]{2}")
    'Regex.Match(text2, "^.*?\\b([^a-zA-Z\\s].?[sa-zA-Z])\\b.*$", RegexOptions.None)

    txbSearch_Term.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Lower

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Do While foundAt > -1

        'count += Regex.Matches(text2, txbsearch.ToString()).Count
        'Regex.Match(txbsearch, "^.*?\\b([^a-zA-Z\\s].?[sa-zA-Z])\\b.*$")
        Dim pattern As String = "^.*?\b([^a-zA-Z\s].?[sa-zA-Z])\b.*$"
        RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
        'Dim input As String = txbsearch

        count += 1

            RichTextBox1.Select(foundAt, txbsearch.Length)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow

            foundAt = RichTextBox1.Find(pattern, foundAt + txbsearch.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)

    Loop

    Dim rowId As Integer = dgvTermCount.Rows.Add()
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvTermCount.Rows(rowId)
    row.Cells("Column1").Value = txbsearch
    row.Cells("Column2").Value = count

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know how vb.net is. But for your problem you could put the results of the regex in a set (python) and count the length of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I have added for each loop and replaced the question mark with all the char I needed from the array each time.

```
    Dim charToReplace() = {"!", Chr(34), "#", "$", "%",
                                "&", "(", ")", "*", "+",
                                ",", "-", ".", "/", ":",
                                ";", "<", "=", ">", "@",
                                "[", "\", "]", "^", "_",
                                "`", "{", "|", "}", "~",
                                "'", " ", "?", "¤", "§", "æ", "ø"}
If txbsearch.Contains("?") Then
    Dim foundAtInt As Integer = 0
        For Each char_ As String In charToReplace
            foundAtInt += 1
            foundAtInt = RichTextBox1.Find(replaceinput.Replace("?", char_), 0, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
                Do While foundAtInt > -1
                    counting += 1
                    RichTextBox1.Select(foundAtInt, replaceinput.Length)
                    RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
                    foundAtInt = RichTextBox1.Find(replaceinput.Replace("?", char_), foundAtInt + replaceinput.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
                Loop
        Next
End If
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for anyone interested in the solution?

Comment: Yes sure @rikyeah

Answer (score 0):

You have have forgotten to quantify your character classes

```
\b([^a-zA-Z\s]+.?[sa-zA-Z]+)\b
              ^           ^
```

Second character class looks weird, with the leading S and all..

Comment: Thank you **Caius Jard** for your reply but unfortunately does not work. The question mark present in input textbox actually is the key that counting should be done in different way, to match and count everything that is same except that ? which is different and is like a wildcard meaning the ? should replace any character in match except letter and number. Please let me know if there a need for more details.

Comment: The solution does not have to be a regular expression it can be like match or wildcart match or any other solution.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what the problem is. The regular expression I provided will find 6 matches for the given example data from the question